# Why eval() is not working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eval

I'm trying to generate UI dynamically in react native from a String fetched from an API. I don't quite get why eval() is not working in this example:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
     {eval('React.createElement(Text, { style: styles.highlight }, `This is my text`)')}

</View>
```

Error:

> ReferenceError: can't find variable: React

Even though I'm getting this error, if I run the same code directly without eval it works perfectly:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
      {React.createElement(Text, { style: styles.highlight }, `This is my text`)}
</View>
```

No error and the text "This is my text" is rendered properly.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'd guess that there's minification going on, so that although `React` is defined before the minifier runs, it's not defined at runtime later. You can check whether I'm correct by inspecting the code that's running at runtime, or by updating your second code block so that instead of the `This is my text` template literal you have `typeof React`.

Comment: It's true, ```<Text>{eval('typeof _React')}</Text>```  outputs "undefined". I guess I need to first convert that javascript String with babel to something executable, but I'm not really sure how to do it :/

Comment: You have an errant `_` in your comment, hopefully not in your real code doing the test...?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The code was actually without the "_". I'm not sure how to edit that comment

Comment: You can't after five minutes, but no worries. :-) Converting the string with Babel probably won't help. If there's minifying/aliasing going on, two separate runs (one on your main code, another when you convert that string) won't necessarily use the same alias for `React`. You could find out what the alias is and, if it looks stable, use that alias, but really you want to avoid evaluating code from strings anyway wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the minification part! I'll try to find other solutions and will post here if I find out something relevant

Comment: @IsmaelDarwishMateos did you find anything useful on this regard?

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti Did you?

Comment: Yes, I had it working at the time, but shifted to triggering functions using an emitter in case React or other components are needed. I didn't test your answer but I suppose it should work

Answer (score 6):

A solution could be to wrap the eval execution inside a function and copy each variable into `this`.

The transpiler/minifier/uglifier won't change the names of the properties of any object, and also won't rename `this` because it's a keyword.

So, something like this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

(function() {
  this.React = React;
  this.Text = Text;  

  eval('this.React.createElement(this.Text, {}, "This is my text")');
})();
```